# using numpy.histogram to bin a dependent variable to an independent variable

Tags: python

I am trying to find a more elegant solution to counting the correspondence between a dependent variable and an independent variable.

I am working with three variables, position (iv), events (dv) and time. For each position, I have a corresponding time, and whenever an event occurs it is recorded as the time it occurred at. I am trying to count the number of times an event occurs at each position. The data looks like this:

```
import random as rand
import numpy as np

rand.seed(11)
event_times = np.array(rand.sample(range(0,900), 20)) /100 # 20 event times over 10 seconds
event_times.sort() 

location = [rand.randrange(0,5,1) for i in range(10)] # 10 positions
timesteps = list(range(0,10)) # 10 times

events_binned, event_bin_ids = np.histogram(event_times, bins = timesteps)
```

and the output looks like this:

```
events
[0.96 1.89 1.9  1.94 4.62 4.63 4.76 4.87 5.2  5.24 5.73 6.01 6.28 6.44
 7.99 8.12 8.23 8.75 8.77 8.86]
location
[3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0, 4, 3, 3, 4]
time
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
events binned by timesteps
[1, 3, 0, 0, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5]
```

I have come up with the following code which gives my desired output of [3, 0, 3, 7, 7]

```
events_location_bin = [int(x) for x in np.zeros(len(loc_bins))]
for idx, val in enumerate(location[:-1]):
    if events_binned[idx] != 0:
        events_location_bin[val] += events_binned[idx]
print(events_location_bin)   

[3, 0, 3, 7, 7]
```

However I'm sure there is a more elegant solution using something like np.histogram that would also be less computationally intensive for larger data sets, but I am struggling to figure out what it would be and I'd be grateful for any help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) operation in pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'location': [3, 2, 1, 0, 4, 0, 4, 3, 3, 4],
                   'events_binned': [1, 3, 0, 0, 4, 3, 3, 1, 5, 0]})

print(df.groupby('location').sum())
```

```
          events_binned
location               
0                     3
1                     0
2                     3
3                     7
4                     7
```

Note that since no event occured after time 9, I appended a 0 to the original `events_binned`, to make the arrays consistent.